# Detect when volume is mounted

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm new with node.js, actually I'm playing with Electron. My app is for configuring device from specific vendor and to read recorded files.

Config is a text file in device root. Recorded files in folder.

I want to know when new device connected and disconnected with mount points. 
I can do this tasks (detect and list mount points) separately but can't figure out how to glue it. 
To have callback on attach/detach I use `node-usb` module and

```
var usb = require('usb'); 
usb.on('attach', ...);
```

But there is no mount points, example of output:

```
{ busNumber: 253,
  deviceAddress: 3,
  deviceDescriptor:
   { bLength: 18,
     bDescriptorType: 1,
     bcdUSB: 528,
     bDeviceClass: 0,
     bDeviceSubClass: 0,
     bDeviceProtocol: 0,
     bMaxPacketSize0: 64,
     idVendor: 34148,
     idProduct: 4096,
     bcdDevice: 4352,
     iManufacturer: 1,
     iProduct: 2,
     iSerialNumber: 3,
     bNumConfigurations: 1 },
  portNumbers: [] }
```

My targeted platforms OS X and Windows. Only way I see is to build native module on C++.

Is there a simple way to achieve this task?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/drivelist

Answer (score 1):

drivelist is a node package to handle mounted volumes: https://github.com/resin-io-modules/drivelist

What you can do is to add it as a dependency and call `drivelist.list()` in an interval, compare the difference of the results of the previous run to the current run to get a list of added or removed volumes.

It supports Windows, macOS and Linux.